# ¿Cómo usar AbstractAccountAuthenticator con Fragmentos?

Tags: android, autenticación

Ya logre crear de manera exitosa una cuenta dentro del dispositivo de la siguiente manera(corrijanme si esta mal):

```
private String analizarRespuesta(final boolean isCredencialesValidos, final Bundle datosUsuario){
    try {
        if (isCredencialesValidos) {
            if (isCuentaExiste()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Actualizar cuenta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return ERROR;
            } else if (crearCuenta(datosUsuario.getString(USUARIO_ID, null), datosUsuario.getString(USUARIO_NOMBRE, null), datosUsuario.getString(USUARIO_APELLIDO, null), datosUsuario.getString(USUARIO_EMAIL, null), datosUsuario.getString(USUARIO_CLAVE, null), datosUsuario.getString(USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL, null), datosUsuario.getString(USUARIO_TOKEN, null), datosUsuario.getStringArray(USUARIO_ROLES))) {
                return INICIAR_SESION_CORRECTO;
            } else {
                return ERROR;
            }
        } else {
            return INICIAR_SESION_INCORRECTO;
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return ERROR;
    }
}

private boolean isCuentaExiste() {
    final Account[] arrayAccount = accountManager.getAccounts();
    for (Account account: arrayAccount) {
        if (account.type.equals(getApplication().getPackageName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean crearCuenta(final String id, final String nombre, final String apellido, final String email, final String clave, final String foto_perfil, final String token, final String[] roles) {
    try {
        if (id == null || id.isEmpty() || nombre == null || nombre.isEmpty() || apellido == null || apellido.isEmpty() || email == null || email.isEmpty() || clave == null || clave.isEmpty() || foto_perfil == null || foto_perfil.isEmpty() || token == null || token.isEmpty() || roles == null || roles.length == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            final Account account = new Account(email, getApplication().getPackageName());
            final Bundle dataUser = new Bundle();
            dataUser.putString(encryption.encryptOrNull(USUARIO_ID), encryption.encryptOrNull(id));
            dataUser.putString(encryption.encryptOrNull(USUARIO_NOMBRE), encryption.encryptOrNull(nombre));
            dataUser.putString(encryption.encryptOrNull(USUARIO_APELLIDO), encryption.encryptOrNull(apellido));
            dataUser.putString(encryption.encryptOrNull(USUARIO_FOTO_PERFIL), encryption.encryptOrNull(foto_perfil));
            dataUser.putStringArray(encryption.encryptOrNull(USUARIO_ROLES), roles);
            accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, encryption.encryptOrNull(clave), dataUser);
            accountManager.setAuthToken(account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, encryption.encryptOrNull(token));
            authenticatorPreferences.setUser(email);
            return true;
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

El primer método `analizarRespuesta` se encarga de analizar la respuesta que viene del servidor para ver si los credenciales que ingreso el usuario para iniciar sesión son validos. Como pueden ver uno de los argumentos del método es `isCredencialesValidos` por lo que esta variable es preguntada si tiene un `true` o `false`, en caso de `true` se llama al siguiente método preguntando si existe una cuenta, porque puede darse el caso que el usuario haya cerrado sesión por lo que la cuenta en el dispositivo esta intacta, solo seria de actualizar los datos de la cuenta, en caso de que el método devuelva un `true` hay que actualizar los datos de la cuenta(eso es una cosa que aun no se como hacer, si me ayudan en esto mas les estaría muy agradecido), en caso que el método `isCuentaExiste` devuelva un `false` quiere decir que la cuenta no existe y que hay que crear una nueva, y se llama al método `crearCuenta`.

Y de esta manera es como creo una cuenta en el dispositivo, pero ahora el problema es el `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`:

```
public class Authenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {

private Context context;

public Authenticator(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Bundle editProperties(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle confirmCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle getAuthToken(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getAuthTokenLabel(String authTokenType) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle updateCredentials(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String authTokenType, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Bundle hasFeatures(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account, String[] features) throws NetworkErrorException {
    return null;
}
}
```

En primer lugar nose exactamente cual es la funcion de esta clase, estaba viendo en algunos post donde en el metodo `addAccount` agregan lo siguiente:

```
@Override
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle options) throws NetworkErrorException {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AuthenticatorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AuthenticatorActivity.ARG_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
    intent.putExtra(AuthenticatorActivity.ARG_AUTH_TYPE, authTokenType);
    intent.putExtra(AuthenticatorActivity.ARG_IS_ADDING_NEW_ACCOUNT, true);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE, response);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountAuthenticator.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
}
```

Por lo que veo se llama a una actividad `AuthenticatorActivity` que esta extendida a `AccountAuthenticatorActivity`, pero yo estoy trabajando con fragmentos, por lo que tengo una sola `Activity` que contiene una fila de fragmentos para iniciar sesión, otra fila de fragmentos para crear cuenta y otra fila de fragmentos para recuperar contraseña, si mi `Activity` lo extiendo a `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` ya no me reconoce el `getSupportFragmentManager`. ¿Como puedo trabajar con fragmentos?. Gracias.